# Coq power operator "^" unfound

Tags: coq, exponential

I'm trying to define a **power function** in Coq, and I can't seem to find the relevant module to import:

```
Require Import Coq.Numbers.NatInt.NZPow.
Definition func (a b : nat) : nat := a+b*2^a.
```

Gives me the following error:

```
Unknown interpretation for notation "_ ^ _".
```

I'm a bit confused, because inside [Coq.Numbers.NatInt.NZPow](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Numbers.NatInt.NZPow.html#), I see the following description:

> Interface of a power function, then its specification on naturals

And also this:

```
Module Type PowNotation (A : Typ)(Import B : Pow A).
 Infix "^" := pow.
End PowNotation.
```

So what am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56635099/how-to-import-theorems-from-coq-numbers-natint-nzdiv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(TLDR; You can to just `Require Import Nat.` to get the `pow` definition and notation for `nat`.

```
Require Import Nat.
Definition func (a b : nat) : nat := a+b*2^a.
```

)

The problem is that you are trying to use a module *type* instead of a module.

The abstract interfaces of `NZPow` need to be instantiated for the specific types.  In the case of `nat` it is already done in the library in [NPeano](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/fb7292570380e0490d7c74db1718725149996ffd/theories/Numbers/Natural/Peano/NPeano.v#L19).   It is just taking the already defined stuff in the "old" `PeanoNat.Nat`, so its very short.  Btw, note the deprecation warning...

```
(** This file is DEPRECATED ! Use [PeanoNat] (or [Arith]) instead. *)

(** [PeanoNat.Nat] already implements [NAxiomSig] *)

Module Nat <: NAxiomsSig := Nat.
```

Anyway, if you insist on using this, you should import `NPeano` which is a module that concretely implements the `NAxsiomsSig` module type for `nat`.  It will just give you the same functions you get when you do `Require Import Nat.`  You can see they are really definitionally the same function with

```
Require Import Init.Nat.
Require Import NPeano.
Check eq_refl: Init.Nat.add = NPeano.Nat.add.
```

(The `Numbers` seem to not have gotten much attention since 2011, so perhaps you should use something more maintained for your work.  OTOH, natural numbers have also been around unchanged for the last 13 billion plus years, so...)

Answer (score 1):

All the `NZ` modules contain *axiomatizations*. They specify the *properties* of functions like `pow` without actually defining them. They do this by using `Module`s. A `Module` is a collection of definitions, notations, etc., and the names and types of those definitions etc. form a `Module Type`. You can "open" a `Module` and use whatever's inside by `Import`ing it, but to do that you need to *have* a module of the correct type in the first place.

`Pow A` is the type of implementations of `pow : A -> A -> A`, and `PowNotation` is the type of modules that contain the notation `Infix "^" := pow`. If you have a `Module` that has type (or supertype!) `PowNotation`, you can `Import` that module to get at that notation. But, again, since the `NZ` modules are just axiomatizations, they *don't* give you such a module and so you *haven't* imported anything that gives you that notation. You can directly import an *actual* implementation:

```
Require Import PeanoNat.
(* The module Nat has type Pow nat, witnessed by Nat.pow : nat -> nat -> nat
   however, it does not have type Pow' nat, so it doesn't actually contain
   Infix "^" := pow.
   The "^" notation is just coming from PeanoNat itself. *)
Definition func (a b : nat) : nat := a+b*2^a.
```

Or you can abstract over the number system in use (so it could be unary `nat`s, or the binary naturals, or the integers, or the integers mod some number, etc.), in the same way that all the `NZ` modules abstract over the number system:

```
Require Import NZAxioms.
Require Import NZPow.

Module Type NZFunc (Import A : Typ) (Import OT : OneTwo' A) (Import ASM : AddSubMul' A) (Import P : Pow' A).
Definition func (a b : t) : t := a+b*2^a.
(* t means A.t, and can be many things depending on the final implementation of this module type *)
(* 2 comes from OT, + from ASM, and ^ from P *)
End NZFunc.
```